# regedit - how to reset to (value not set)

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-registry, regedit

Let's say the key is HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell, 
[image]

and i edit the value to empty

[image]

Then how can this registry key **reset back to (value not set)** state ? I tried `reg add HKCR\Folder\Shell /t REG_SZ /f`(without /d) but no luck.

Comment: What's the significance of this "value not set"? Why is it important for you to have that state? From a functional viewpoint, they're the same

Comment: None and empty string is different in programming viewpoint, and i'm not registry expert to know t is there any side effect to left it empty. The quickest and safest way is reset to how its original look like.

Comment: I'm not a programmer either. Unless you know that there is a functional difference, I'd assume that there is no difference. They're both Null.

Comment: I don't know "functional difference" or not, that's why i ask. Windows is closed source, how you know the hidden functionality powered by hidden source code ? What if this empty string for this particular registry key will crash one app in future ? Null and empty string is difference stuff in coding.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just delete it. The default stays there with (value not set)

Comment: Is there a method without 'deleting' it?...  as that's not a trivial method if there are many peer values & subkeys (& yes, I know you can export the key, delete it, then re-add it with the changes/deletions made; but I'm hoping there's a more elegant approach.

Comment: Delete the STRING (default), not the KEY it's in.